# Как поймать "кадровый диалог" двух компов с помощью WireShark?

Tags: сеть, wireshark

Привет.

Разбираюсь в WireShark и сетями. Как можно словить (какой фильтр) только те кадры, которые идут МЕЖДУ двумя компами?  Знаю, что можно словить фильтром, например, те кадры, которые отсылает через мою сетевую карту - пишу для этого ПРОСТОЙ фильтр *eth.src == xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx* . Как поймать "кадровый диалог" двух компов? Может быть, есть какие-то составные (сложные) фильтры.

Хочу словить последовательно все пакеты, которые идут между двумя программами (программой-клиентом-браузером и и программой веб-сервером) на двух компах, чтобы лучше понять, как работает это дело.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точно так же.

```
(eth.src == mac1 or eth.src == mac2) and (eth.dst == mac1 or eth.dst == mac2)
```

Comment: я реализовал немного по-другому - (eth.src == mac1 and eth.dst == mac2) or (eth.src == mac2 and eth.dst == mac1). но выдало какую-то кашу непонятную

Comment: Тоже правильный вариант.
А про кашу - может, у вас нет доступа к данным этих потоков?

Comment: я задал фильтр, получил результат, который не могу описать. цель была такая - увидеть своими глазами, как из кусочков-пакетов собираются данные (например, хтмл-документ или увидеть, как из кусков данных собирается картинка.) на сетевом уровне. именно сетевой уровень стека TCP/IP занимается сборкой данных в один кусок из поступающих кусков при получении данных или наоборот - разбивает при отправлении. не понимаю, где это можно увидеть своими глазами.

Comment: В снифере вы увидите поток пакетов. Некоторые снифера умеют некоторые типы данных (html, например) представлять в человекочитаемой форме. Ваша задача по-прежнему остаётся непонятна. Вам надо отладить взаимодействие? Увидеть, где передаются неверные данные? Это лучше ловить на уровне приложения, писать данные не только в сеть, но и в лог.

Comment: я хотел увидеть, как данные передаются от веб-сервера клиенту в виде TCP-сегментов, потом эти сегменты складываются вместе и обернутые заголовком HTTP передаются выше - с транспортного уровня на уровень прикладной. моя задача - пощупать руками, как работает передача данных

Comment: Ну тогда вдумчиво читайте кашу из пакетов, которые вам наловил снифер. Там всё есть :), начиная с ethernet-уровня.